# How to output multiple dimension array

Tags: r, arrays, export-to-csv

I created a mutiple dimension array called, decision, and I want to output the array into csv files, e.g. `decision[,,1]`; `decision[,,2]`; ...; `decision[,,36]` into different files, can I use some function to output them in one time?
instead of using

```
write.csv(decision[,,1],file="data1.csv")
write.csv(decision[,,36],file="data36.csv")
```

Comment: Try `Map(function(i,j) write.csv(decision[,,i],j), 1:36, paste0("data",1:36,".csv"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

# example data
decision <- array(runif(10 * 5 * 4), dim = c(10, 5, 4))

purrr::walk(1:dim(decision)[3], ~ write.csv(arr[,,.x], file = paste0("data", .x, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE))
```